# C Function Pointer assignment

Tags: c, embedded, function-pointers

As far as I read when you declare a function pointer, there is not assignment to a left hand side or right hand side. But I have numerous function pointers in a C source file and all are used in an assignment form like below:

```
void (*pbindRemoveDev)( zAddrType_t *Addr ) = (void*)NULL;
```

Can anybody can help me understand (void*)NULL part?

This is an embedded code.

Comment: There is no initialization syntax for a *function declaration*. But, you can always initialize a *pointer* variable.

Comment: Function __pointer__ is not the same as function __definition__ (or prototype declaration).

Comment: Who the hell casts `NULL` to `void *`? In C, it's completely redundant (`NULL` is already a void pointer), and in C++, the cast only breaks things (as there is no implicit conversion from void pointers to other pointers).

Comment: the function returns void*, so that is why the null is being cast. However, since NULL is (usually) defined as a void*(0), there is no need to use the cast on the indicated statement

Comment: How is `NULL` defined in your project(`#define NULL (0)`)?

Comment: @user3629249: Even if `Addr`would point to a function returning an `int` (or any other type) `NULL` will be valid to initialise it. No, no need to cast.

Comment: Guys I don't know why NULL is cast to a void pointer. I have same question. This is a standard code and it's correct.

Answer (score 5):

There is no assignment in

```
void (*pbindRemoveDev)( zAddrType_t *Addr ) = (void*)NULL;
```

It is initializing function pointer `pbindRemoveDev` to `NULL`. Following is the assignment

```
void RemoveDev( zAddrType_t *Addr );
pbindRemoveDev = RemoveDev // Assignment
```

Comment: 1+ for pointing out that this is an *initilaisation* and that this is something different than an *assignmet*.

Comment: That's a bit besides the point though because the version using assignment still works and behaves equivalently. The OP's assumption that you can't assign function pointers is simply false.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly like :

```
int a;
```

But here the type is :

```
void (*)(zAddrType_t*)
```

So yes, you can do `int a = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

It is a function pointer declaration. Your code initializes it to NULL.

```
void (*pbindRemoveDev)( zAddrType_t *Addr ) = (void*)NULL;
```

Unaware the compiler you're using, proper initializationn could be

```
void (*pbindRemoveDev)( zAddrType_t *Addr ) = NULL;
```

If you invoke the function pointer it will crash since you're pointing to NULL memory address.

Below is a function pointer initialization example:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void bar(int x)
 {
      printf( "%d\n", x );
 }

 int main()
 {

        void (*foo)(int) = &bar;
        foo(10); //This prints 10.

        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: To stay accurate: This is a *definition* not just a *declaration* of the function pointer `Addr `.